# Diferencia de dias SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente problema, quiero que me muestre en una columna cuantos días faltan para mi próximo cumpleaños.

ya probé las siguientes funciones DATEDIFF y DATEADD

Les dejo mi sentencia a la que faltaría agregarle dicha columna:

```
select dc.fecha_nacimiento as cumple from datos_cliente dc
```

Comment: Aparte de esto, averiguaste algo sobre diferencia de fechas en sql server?

Comment: si utilice datadiff y dateAdd pero no le encuentro la vuelta

Comment: Genial, agrega esos ejemplos, para que nadie responda lo mismo que ya hiciste. Mientras mas completa la pregunta, mejores respuestas obtenes Ademas de esa forma, no parece que estas pidiendo que hagan las cosas por vos. mira [ask]

Comment: gracias por el comentario!

Comment: edita tu pregunta usando el boton [edit], agrega todo eso que probaste y no funciono, y seguro vas a tener una respuesta ;)

Comment: que probaste con datediff que no funciono? porque la respuesta a tu pregunta es esa

Comment: Puedes utilizar un subquery en tu consulta (aunque no es muy elegante ni eficiente) 

  select dc.fecha_nacimiento as cumple,
  ,(SELECT DATEDIFF(day, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, dc.fecha_nacimiento, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
       + CASE WHEN DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, dc.fecha_nacimiento, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), dc.fecha_nacimiento) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, dc.fecha_nacimiento))) as dias_restantes_para_cumple
  
  from datos_cliente dc

Comment: Gracias alfredo me sirvio!

Answer (score 0):

Realice la prueba y me funciono prueba tu a ver:

```
--OBTENGO LA DIFERENCIA DE AÑOS DESDE LA FECHA INDICADA A LA FECHA ACTUAL
SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, '1994-07-08', GETDATE())

--AÑADO LA CANTIDAD DE AÑOS OBTENIDA EN EL PASO ANTERIOR
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '1994-07-08', GETDATE()), '1994-07-08')

--SI LA FECHA OBTENIDA ES MENOR A LA FECHA ACTUAL DEVUELVO 1 PARA SUMAR UN AÑO MÁS
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '1994-07-08', GETDATE()), '1994-07-08') < GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

--FECHA FINAL DEL PROXIMO CUMPLEAÑOS
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '1994-07-08', GETDATE()) + CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '1994-07-08', GETDATE()), '1994-07-08') < GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, '1994-07-08')

--OBTENGO LA DIFERENCIA EN DÍAS DESDE LA FECHA ACTUAL A LA FECHA FINAL OBTENIDA DEL PRÓXIMO CUMPLEAÑOS
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '1994-07-08', GETDATE()) + CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '1994-07-08', GETDATE()), '1994-07-08') < GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, '1994-07-08'))

--TU CASO
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, dc.fecha_nacimiento, GETDATE()) + CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, dc.fecha_nacimiento, GETDATE()), dc.fecha_nacimiento) < GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, dc.fecha_nacimiento)) AS cumple FROM datos_cliente dc
```

Esta es la [fuente](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/228478/birthday-count-down-from-database-only-days-left-f).